# session vs profile to store userID in an extremely simple vb.netapp

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, session, authentication, profile

I am building an extremely simple VB.net web application that uses Visual Studio's forms authentication. As part of this- I am trying to capture the userID upon login and use it while the user is in the app (to dynamically display information via dataset/gridview that is associated with that userID) so I don't have to give them their userID and prompt them for it constantly.

The app is very simple and uses a local DB to do all the authentication (Users, User_Activation, Roles)

This app will have 9-10 users that will be consistent over the years(logging in 10-15 times a year), and 40-50 rotating users that log in once or twice and do not return past that year.

The profiles and authentication/sessions do not need to handle tons of users and authentication requests.

I also want to avoid cookies because I want to keep everything as simple, and centralized to the application as possible.

I have explored building a GetUserID function that queries the database based on the userName every time a user takes an action (button click, page load) that requires the userID. But I am having trouble with the SQL and it seems bulky.

I have also looked into sessions- but they seem unreliable and difficult to manage.(How do i keep each session separate as users login?)

I am now looking at Profiles 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2y3fs9xs.aspx

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.profile.sqlprofileprovider.aspx

I think I can just use the default instance of the SqlProfileProvider and point it to my database I already have built?

I am very new to programming and am not sure how complex the configuration would be for the Profiles, so any guidance or advice would be greatly appreciated!

I can post any code snippets needed, or upload the app to github or something if that helps at all.

Thanks!

Comment: You need a client side persistence layer, so when you say no to `session` and `cookie` you took out 2 options that accomplish it (persist data specific to a user). Look into the newer [ASP.Net identity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/security/) - even the default scaffolding already has about ~70% of the work "done" for you. That said this topic is unfortunately too broad for SO and will be opinionated. Hth.

Comment: Please see my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47378896/one-time-login-process/47391851#47391851)